# Displaying content stored in database(SQL Server) on MVC view

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following stored on database

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mqSQvoinDE4" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I try to display it using `@Html.Raw` or `@Html.DisplayFor` it displays plain HTML instead of showing this iframe which is basically youtube embed .

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: When you say `@Html.Raw` displays the plain HTML, is that not what you want? Does it just show the HTML as text? It should render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this inside the @Html.Raw:

```
Server.HtmlDecode(Model.iFrameHTML)
```